# How to get data for a specific User using their uid?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to get data for a specific user, which I know its uid, I want to retrieve all the data that is for that specific user. Can you help me on how to retrieve the user data?
Thank you in advance

```
func grabbingData() {
    let specificDatabase = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Data")
    let query = specificDatabase.queryOrdered(byChild: "uid").queryEqual(toValue: "ghD0lYZV1QOeJ2giUc3fNVxsLAV2")
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapShot) in
        for child in snapShot.children {
            if let snap = child as? DataSnapshot {
                if let dictValues = snap.value as? [String: [String:String]] {
                    Array(dictValues.values).forEach {
                        let data = Data()
                        data.Name = $0["Name"]!
                        data.hold = $0["Data"]!
                        data.uid = $0["uid"]!
                        self.requestArray.append(data)
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

---

```
Firebase Structure

"Data" : {
    "ghD0lYZV1QOeJ2giUc3fNVxsLAV2" : {
        "-LlhLo-NJRn68ThFSAL2" : {
            "Name" : "Fake",
            "Data" : "data",
            "uid" : "ghD0lYZV1QOeJ2giUc3fNVxsLAV2"
        },
        "-Llc_-M2tU9bm-AqcTb5" : {
            "Name" : "Fake",
            "Data" : "data",
            "uid" : "ghD0lYZV1QOeJ2giUc3fNVxsLAV2"
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presented Firebase structure has some possibly unneeded duplication of the uid and it's unclear why but here's some code to read the structure in the question and print out the child values within each child node

```
func readUserNode() {
    let userNodeRef = self.ref.child("Data").child("ghD0lYZV1QOeJ2giUc3fNVxsLAV2")
    userNodeRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let allChildNodes = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for child in allChildNodes {
            let name = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "Name").value as? String ?? "no name"
            let data = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "Data").value  as? String ?? "no data"
            let uid = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "uid").value  as? String ?? "no uid"
            print(name, data, uid)
        }
    })
}
```

and the output (I changed Fake to Fake1 and Fake2 so you could see each node is printed)

```
Fake1 data ghD0lYZV1QOeJ2giUc3fNVxsLAV2
Fake2 data ghD0lYZV1QOeJ2giUc3fNVxsLAV2
```

To address the question further.

With Firebase you only need to query for data when you don't which nodes the data was stored in. In other words, for this use case, you know the users uid (ghD0lYZV1QOeJ2giUc3fNVxsLAV2) and the data you are after is stored in a node with that uid as the key.

Because of that, the node can be directly accessed without a query.

Comment: It’s not duplicate at all, and I use query because I need to find a specific user data

Comment: @JoseGarcia You are not finding specific user data; you already know the uid of the user so you don't need to query for it or duplicate it in the child nodes because it's the key to the node itself. See the explanation in my answer.

Comment: Will try right now and let you know if it is correct and I will check mark it

Comment: It works, thanks for explainng to me when to use query